# Ifstream file does not open although everything seems in place (c++)

Tags: c++, file, ifstream

I'm trying to write a program to parse the first and sixteenth columns of a CSV file (converted into .txt). I have the CSV ("posts.txt") document in the folder with the executable. But, whenever I try to run the executable, my program delivers that it cannot open the file (or that "!infile.is_open()"). Mind giving me some assistance? I'm running in Xcode 3.2.3 on Mac OSX 10.8.3. The code is shows below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

void answeredPostGrabber()
{
    ifstream inFile("posts.txt");

    string postNumber;
    string answerNumber;
    string throwAway;

    if(inFile.is_open())
    {

        while(inFile.good())
        {
            getline(inFile,postNumber,',');
            cout << postNumber << ",";

            for(int y=1;y++;y<16)
            {
                getline(inFile,throwAway,',');
            }
            getline(inFile,answerNumber,',');
            cout << answerNumber << endl;

            ofstream edges;
            edges.open("edges.txt",ios::app);
            edges << postNumber << "," << answerNumber<< endl;
            edges.close();

            ofstream nodes;
            nodes.open("nodes.txt",ios::app);
            nodes << postNumber << "\n" << answerNumber << endl;
            nodes.close();

            getline(inFile,throwAway);
          }
   }else cout << "ERROR: Unable to open file." << endl;
}

int main ()
{
    answeredPostGrabber();
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you set the working directory to that in which `posts.txt` is located? If you run it from within XCode, that will likely not be the case. Otherwise, are the file permissions correct?

Comment: Why don't you create a dummy file and then go and find it. That's where this file that can't be found *should* be.

Answer (score 6):

> I have the CSV ("posts.txt") document in the folder with the executable.

The file should be present in the **[current working directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) of your process**, which may or may not be the same directory where the executable lives. If in doubt, try specifying the full path in `ifstream inFile(...);` to see whether that changes things.

Additionally, the file needs to have the correct permissions to ensure that it's readable by the process.

Comment: I tried to use ifstream to create a dummy file (   ifstream infile("asdf.txt");), but when I ran the program with it, the program never created the file (anywhere on my computer!). I believe all of the permissions are correct. Hm... What now? Is there any familiar XCode error with not creating files?