# How can I solve the "error reading characters of string"?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I wrote a code to read data from text file as follows;

```
const char* gm_Rec_unfin = "unfin_rec.txt";

ifstream infile(gm_Rec_unfin);
auto unfin = read_rec(infile);

if (!infile.good())
    cout << "fail to read a file!" << endl;
```

after compiling and running these codes, I got "failed to read a file!".

and in the debugging this, I got the following messages;

- infile    {_Filebuffer={_Set_eback=0xcccccccc  _Set_egptr=0xcccccccc  ...} }    std::basic_ifstream >

  ```
  std::basic_ios<char,std::char_traits<char> >    <Unable to read memory>
  ```

before I post this questions, I found so many similar questions in here and tried their solution. however, it didn't work unfortunately. what can i do to solve these problem?

thanks for your advice in advance.

cheers,

seihyung

Comment: Before reading data you should check to make sure the file was even opened. Make sure the `txt` file is in the working directory of the program - See [Ifstream file does not open although everything seems in place](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17462950/ifstream-file-does-not-open-although-everything-seems-in-place-c)

Comment: @Captain Obvlious, I made sure the file was in the working directory of the program and file's permission is OK.

Answer (score 0):

Don't check `std::ios::good` after reading. Check `std::ios::fail`, or `operator bool`.